# Java&JDBC - Получение значения из столбца

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

появилась проблема.

Есть база данных, и в ней есть таблица и столбцы.
Нужно получить из столбца типа String значение, но так как я только сегодня начал знакомится с работой с базами данных в Java, то сделать тут мало чего могу.

Из интернета вычитал, вроде как способ получения, вот код:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM `Awesome database`");
System.out.println(resultSet);
String first = resultSet.getString("username");
```

Но он выводит программу в стек трейс:

> java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Возможно, что это к моей проблеме даже и не относится, я не знаю :D

Кто сможет помочь, буду благодарен :)

Comment: Попробуйте загуглить вашу ошибку, я уверен, вы не первый кто такое наблюдает. Мне кажется, вы как то неправильно используете `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Означает, что надо сдвинуть указатель `ResultSet` перед тем как прочитать его значение, обычно делается так:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM `Awesome database`");
while(rs.next()) { //сдвижка указателя 
    String first = resultSet.getString("username");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно так попробовать.

```
  public void idPhone(String username) throws SQLException {

    try (Connection c = getConnection()) {
        String sql = ""SELECT username FROM name database where username = ?  ";

        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.execute();
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

             String idPhone = rs.getString("username");

            System.out.println(username);
        }


    }

}

  public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usb_key", "root", "root");


}
```